# Why can't I use the cast operator in comparisions?

Tags: c++, typecast-operator

Assume the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    operator int()
    {
        return 123;
    }
    operator string()
    {
        return string("abc");
    }
};
void main()
{
    A a;
    cout<<(a==123)<<endl;
    //cout<<(a==string("abc"))<<endl;
}
```

First, I compare object `a` with an `int` variable. Then, I attempt to compare it with a `string` variable, but the program files to compile. With the line containing the comparison commented out, it compiles just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you get a compiler error? What does it say? Did that tell you anything? Like maybe that there's no `==` operator overload available for those parameter types?

Comment: Try to make such operators `const` correct, so that you can use them for `const A object;`. e.g `operator int () const { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided the conversion operators for your class to `int` as well as `std::string`,
That ensures the conversion happens appropriately.
However, for the `==` to work the types being compared must have an `==` defined.
The language provides an implicit `==` for `int` type but `==` operator overload for `std::string` and hence the error.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, "int comparison is a language feature, but string comparison is a library feature"?

Comment: @KerrekSB: In a nutshell, `std::string` comparison using `operator ==` is not required by the language specification but perhaps could be a feature provided by the library.

Comment: -1 This seems to be all wrong. The C++ standard describes std::string alright. And it all has to do with `operator==` being a template or not, and not with it being a user-defined overload vs built-in.